# NodeJS sendFile with File Name in download

Tags: node.js, express, sendfile

I try to send file to client with this code:

```
router.get('/get/myfile', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile("/other_file_name.dat");
});
```

it's work fine but I need that when user download this file from the url:

```
http://mynodejssite.com/get/myfile
```

the filename into the browser must be "other_file_name.dat" and not "myfile".

Comment: do you have other routes that match that endpoint signature?  Like:  router.get('/get/:filename', (req, res) => {})

Comment: Yes I've "/get/myfile1", "/get/myfile2", "/get/myfile..."

Comment: are you using a colon to create a route param anywhere?  Also do you have just a router.get('/get') before you show the other ones?

Comment: I found the solution. Tomorrow I share it with you. Thank you so much

Answer (score 33, accepted):

there is a specialized method [res.download](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download)

which covers all for you ;)

```
router.get('/get/myfile', function (req, res) {
    res.download("/file_in_filesystem.dat", "name_in_browsers_downloads.dat");
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const transfer = exports;

transfer.responseFile = function (basePath, fileName, res) {
    var fullFileName = path.join(basePath, fileName);

    fs.exists(fullFileName, function (exist) {
        if (exist) {
            var filename = path.basename(fullFileName);

            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
            res.setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');

            res.sendFile(fullFileName)
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });
};
```

and use it:

```
router.get('/myfile', function (req, res) {
    transfer.responseFile("/var/nodejs", 'fileToDownload.dat', res);
});
```

Thank you to all helpers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple routes like below:
"/get/myfile1", "/get/myfile2", "/get/myfile

Why don't you make a generic one. which can handle all request and it will solve your link(download_name) problem too. You can do it as below

```
router.get('/get/:fileName',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('/file_path/'+req.params.fileName)
});
```

**Edit After Comment (EDIT 1):**

Sorry, i didn't get your point. I am assuming that if you are developing the backend api, you should have the control of choosing the url too, right ?

Giving an example:

when server side is this:

```
router.get('/get/:fileName',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('/file_path/'+req.params.fileName)
});
```

Based on your posted code and implementation. The files which need to get downloaded are finite in number and known files.

assuming there are 2 files : "file1.dat" and "file2.dat"

you can call the api as below right ?

1. http://yourapi.com/get/file1.dat
2. http://yourapi.com/get/file2.dat

am i missing something ?

**EDIT 2:**

If that is the case, i think this would solve your problem, instead of using sendFile use res.attachment:

```
app.get('/get/myfile',function(req,res){
        res.attachment('/file.txt');
        res.end('Downloaded', 'UTF-8')
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution but the problem is that the original filename is different by the url.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your point. I am assuming that if you are developing the backend api, you should have the control of choosing the url too, right ?

Giving an expample:

when server side is this: 

router.get('/get/:fileName',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('/file_path/'+req.params.fileName)
});

Based on your posted code and implementation. The files which need to get downloaded are finite in number and known files.

assuming there are 2 files : "file1.dat" and "file2.dat"

you can call the api as below right ?
1. yourapi.com/get/file1.dat
2. yourapi.com/get/file2.dat

Comment: No, the url need to be without the filename and without extension.

Comment: Let me know if Edit 2 fixed your issue

Comment: app.get('/get/myfile',function(req,res){
        res.attachment('/file.txt');
        res.send('/file.txt');
});

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in case is useful for someone

`res.sendFile('filepath', { headers: { 'filename': 'myfile' } }, (error) => errorHandlerFunc() )`