# Download a file with a custom name expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

i have an `app.get` that when it's called it downloads a file, here's the code:

```js
app.get("/download-file", async (req, res) => {
      if (req.ip === ip0 || req.ip === ip1)
        res.download(`${__dirname}/progetto.odt`, "Progetto Esame.odt");
      else res.status(403).send("Ip non autorizzato!");
    })
```

I don't think that the if-else thingy is doing something, I saw on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941724/nodejs-sendfile-with-file-name-in-download) link that I should add that `"progetto esame.odt"` as the second parameter and vs code says so too, but it still downloads as `download-file`. How can I get this working?

P.S. I'm downloading the file from a react website with a button that calls the API with an `href="http://localhost:3001/download-file"`, maybe that's the problem?

P.P.S. I tried with Opera and Firefox, both are not working as they should

---

Node version: 16.6.2

Express version: 4.17.1

Comment: you have not defined `ip0`, nor `ip1`

Comment: While this isn't a [mcve], I can say: use braces around `if`s and `else`s and use `path.join` instead of `${foo}/bar`. What's the point of the function being `async` if you never use `await`? Lots of code smell here.

Comment: That's not the problem, in the original code, these are my two machines ips: ip0 and ip1. these two are just substitutes. I also said that it downloaded the file but with the wrong name .-.

Comment: You could also try setting the Content-Disposition header I believe.

Comment: I'm actually just used to using ``async`` in function, my bad here, I'll also follow your suggestions on the ``path.join()`` and for the bracers. Thanks
any ideas for the actual problem though?

Comment: What do you mean by "Content-Disposition header"?

Comment: must be your browser the method works fine, https://68821447.lcherone.repl.co/download-file = https://replit.com/@lcherone/68821447#index.js

Comment: i'll try with another browser and update the question then, thanks for the advice